# Why is steps count different in Health and Activity App in my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, health.app, activity.app

[image] [image]

As apparent, the steps count appear out of sync in Health and Activity app when viewed at the same time. Both are first party apps.

What is the reason for discrepancy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have a difference of 95 steps over a total of 19000 steps; it looks like a rounding error.

Or maybe the Apple Watch has not yet uploaded the latest steps to the iPhone (it does this every few minutes, in order to save battery).